Rewrites Nextjs not change path from another domain to main domain
I am having a problem using rewritestext in nextjs to change the api route from one link to another due to deploying both sources in vercel (side project). Before that feature was working fine, but now after the latest deploys, that feature is not working.
Does anyone know about the update of vercel, nextjs about changing the route. Thanks
return [
      {
        source: '/api/:path*',
        destination: `${API_URL}/:path*`,
      },
    ];

i was try this few last month, it work, but now not work. idn know why?

Do you have a minimal repro?
